# Number of 5 letter words with at least two consecutive letters same

Tags: combinatorics

> How many 5-letter words have at least two consecutive letters which are the same?

I tried to break this up into the following cases:

> 2 consecutive letters same: $4*26*1*25^3$
>
> 3 consecutive letters same: $3*26*1^2*25^2$
>
> 4 consecutive letters same: $2*26*1^3*25$
>
> 5 consecutive letters same: $26$

Upon adding these cases I got $1675076$.

However, the proper answer is $1725126$ and can be attained through complementary counting.

Why did splitting the problem up into cases not work?

Comment: First, you're counting some words twice here. For example the word AABBB would get counted in both of the first two lines. Second, your calculations aren't considering permutations. For example, the sequences { AAA, B, C } can be arranged in 6 different ways, but you're multiplying by 3.

Comment: For reasons tangentstorm and Andre bring up it's a very difficult problem to do the way you opted to do it. That's why it's much simpler to do, as you later mention, by complementary counting as, $26^5 - 26 \times 25^4$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider for example the first term $(4)(26)(25)^3$. There are is more than one interpretation of the $25^3$. Perhaps the $25^3$ is motivated by "once we have chosen the double, say aa, and where it is, the remaining $3$ slots can be filled in $25^3$ ways with non-a's." Under this interpretation of the $25^3$, we are  double-counting some possibilities and failing  to count some possibilities.

It double-counts, for example, the word aabbx, and many others.

It fails to count the word aaxay, and many others.

But there is **another** interpretation of the $25^3$. We are say constructing a word that starts with aa. Then if we want to avoid **further** doubles, we have $25$ choices for the next letter, and for each choice we have $25$ choices for the next letter, and so on.

This **does** count aabab, which is good. But it fails to count aabbx. So it is not surprising that we get an undercount. It would be interesting to count the double-double words, and address the same issue with strings of type aaabb. With some care, one should get a correct count.

Comment: Could you please explain how it double counts "aabbx" and doesn't count "aaxay"? This was my thought process. There are 4 possible positions for the two consecutive letters. There are 26 choices for the first repeated character and the other repeated character has no choice. Then each of the other three characters are either next to the two repeated characters or they are not. If they are next to the repeated characters, you can choose any of the 25 letters not used by the repeated characters. If they are not next to the repeated characters, they can be anything except the letter next to it.

Comment: (continued). Thus this gives $4*26*25^3$. I don't see how this fails to count "aaxay" and how it double counts some?

Comment: First, fail to count. You correctly allowed the possibility that "the" double occurs in the first $2$, the next $2$, and so on. Take for instance the case it occurs in the first $2$, and is say aa. Presumably $25^3$ counts the number of permutations of non-a's. But that leaves out aaxay. As to double-counting, consider the word ccxdd. It got counted among the words that begin with $2$ consecutives. It also got counted among the words that end in $2$ consecutives.

Comment: I have given one interpretation of your $25^3$. Under another interpretation, you did not count $aaxbb$.

Comment: Ok, yeah I understood now. Thanks!