# Number of 5 letter words with at least one double letter

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

**How many 5 letter words have at least one double letter, i.e. two consecutive
letters that are the same?**

Answer is:
$26^5 – 26*25^4 = 1,725,126 $

But how can i solve? I don't understand.

The book took all situation $26^5$ and then subtrack $26*25^4$ situation. I think in $26*25^4$ situation that there is some double letter also.

Can you explain the answer more deeply.

*I found this : [Number of 5 letter words with at least two consecutive letters same](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/740332/number-of-5-letter-words-with-at-least-two-consecutive-letters-same) but there is no answer for that.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution subtracts from total, the number of sequences where no two consecutive letters are the same. Now first letter has $26$ options, second has $25$ ( different from first ) third has again $25$ options ( can be same as first but different from second) same is the case for fourth and fifth letter. Thus solution subtracts $26*25^4$.

Comment: It is too easy, i need to sleep now. How can't i realize 25*25 is not the same letter. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: How many five letter words are there with no double letters? Any of $26$ letters is possible for the first letter of the word; given the first letter, how many choices are there for the second? Given the second, how many choices are there for the third?

Once we have this count, we can simply subtract it from the number of (unconstrained) words of $5$ letters (we have $26$ options for each of five letters, so this count is $26^5$ as indicated).

> In the first count, there are $25$ choices for each letter after the first, so there are $26 \cdot 25^4$ words with no double letters, leaving $26^5 - 26 \cdot 25^4$ words with double letters.

Comment: just out of curiosity , when is this grey region used for answering ?

Comment: I don't think it's ever obligatory, but for questions that appear to be homework (or where I think OP might like to work out some details him- or herself), I like to write out some hints or the beginning of a solution, and then, situation depending, hide a hint, or the rest of a worked solution, or just a final answer in a grey mouseover region, so that OP (or anyone else) has the option to work out the problem on their own without having all of it spoiled.

Comment: Traits of an experienced user I guess :)

Comment: I learned about it not so long ago, actually, but I think it makes the site more useful for other participants, so I took up the habit myself.