# How many 4-digit numbers have at least two consecutive digits that are the same?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

How many $4$-digit numbers have at least two consecutive digits that are the same?

Solve this problem in two ways, and explain both solutions:

(a) Use PIE.

(b) Use complementary counting.

Comment: Any thoughts?  Easy enough to count the ones with no matching consecutive digits...Lead digit can be any of $9$ (assuming it can not start with $0$).  Next can be $0$ but can't match the lead, hence $9$ possibilities again, and so on.

Comment: Take a look here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/740332/number-of-5-letter-words-with-at-least-two-consecutive-letters-same?rq=1

Comment: It will be helpful if you post what you have done in an attempt to solve this problem, rather than just asking your question.

Comment: what is PIE?${}{}{}{}$

Comment: PIE is short for Principle of Inclusion and Exclusion.

Comment: So pie would be to figure how many 4 digit numbers total there are, and subtract those that have no consecutive digits the same, right? What is complementary ciunting.

Comment: What's the difference between PIE and complementary counting.

Comment: @fleablood: In this case complementary counting is Inclusion/Exclusion done efficiently. One can also use less efficient versions of Inclusion/Exclusion.

Comment: So... "less efficient".... all numbers minus those with with the first two, second two, last two consecutive + pluss thos with first two and second two, second and third, and first and third minus those with all consecutive the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mong him ng did complimentary counting.  Here is (the much less efficient) PIE.

Let A= those with the first two digit the same.  B = those with the second two digits the same.  C = those with the last two digits the same.

Our set, E, at least two digits the same will be the union of these minus "double counting", plus those we double counted in reducing our double counting, etc.

i.e

$E = A \cup B \cup C$.

But as A, B, C are not disjoint.

$|E| = (|A| + |B| + |C|) - (|A \cap B| + |A \cap C| + |B \cap C|) + (|A \cap B \cap C|)$.

For A, there are $9$ choices for the first two digits (as the first digit can not be 0) and 10 for all the other digits.  So $|A| = 9*10*10 = 900$.

For B, there are $9$ choices for the first digit, 10 for the second two, and 10 for the fourth digit. So $|B| = 9*10*10 = 900$.

$|C| = 900$ for the same reason that |B| is.

For $A \cap B$, there are 9 options for the first three digits and 10 for the fourth digit.  So $|A \cap B| = 9*10 = 90$.

For $A \cap C$ there are 9 options for the first two digits and 10 for the third and fourth.  So $|A \cap C| = 9*10$ = 90.

For $B \cap C$ there are 9 options for the first digit and 10 for the remaining three.  $|B\cap C|= 90$

For $A \cap B \cap C$ all four digits are the same as the first digit.  There are 9 options.

So $|E| = (900 + 900 + 900) - (90 + 90 + 90) + 9 = 2700 - 270 + 9 = 2439$.

Answer (score 2):

I only know how to do this by complementary counting:

(All 4-digit number) - (All 4-digit numbers with no consecutive digits that are the same)

### All 4-digit number:

This is simply 1000 to 9999 inclusive, for a total of 9000 distinct numbers.

### All 4-digit numbers with no consecutive digits that are the same:

We can count this through constructive counting. For the thousand digit, we have 9 possibilities (1 to 9, 0 is not an option). For the hundred digit, we have 10 possibilities (0 to 9). However, Since consecutive digits must not be the same, we have now only 9 possibilities (discarding whatever number the thousand digit is). The same goes for the tens and unit digit.

For a total of $9^4 = 6561$ possibilities.

Subtract the two, there are $9000 - 6561 = 2439$ of such numbers.

Answer (score 0):

We  apply PIE  and start  by drawing  the poset  for  counting 4-digit
numbers with  no consecutive digits that  are the same  (these are the
positions  that  guaranteed  to   have  equal  values,  there  may  be
additional equalities)

```
  +---------------()----------------+
  |               |                 |
(12)      +------(23)-------+       (34)
  +-------+-----+   +-------+-------+
  |       |     |   |       |       |
  +---(123)    (12)(34)   (234)-----+
        |         |         |
        |         |         |
        +-------(1234)------+
```

Now putting  weights on  these (computing the  Mobius function  of the
poset) we get

```
  +---------------()[1]-------------+
  |               |                 |
(12)[-1]  +------(23)[-1]---+       (34)[-1]
  +-------+-----+   +-------+-------+
  |       |     |   |       |       |
  +---(123)[1] (12)(34)[1] (234)[1]--+
        |         |         |
        |         |         |
        +-------(1234)[-1]--+
```

We thus obtain

$$9\times 10^3 - 9\times 10^2 - 9\times 10\times 10
- 9\times 10\times 10
\\ + 9\times 10 + 9\times 10 + 9\times 10
- 9 = 6561.$$

This yields for the numbers with at least two digits the same
$$9000-6561 = 2439.$$